# Подскажите, что не так с кодом. Где может быть ошибка?

Tags: python

Текстовый файл содержит только заглавные буквы латинского алфавита (ABC…Z). Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, среди которых не более одной буквы A.

```
f = open('24 (23).txt').read()
lst = []
n = ''
for i in range(len(f)):
    n += f[i]
    if n.count('A') > 1:
        lst.append(len(n))
        n = 'A'
print(max(lst))
```

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Кто так задания вообще формулирует. "Идущие подряд символы" - это, например, "DDDDD" или "ABCDEF"?

Comment: @CrazyElf это задача с ЕГЭ по информатике, причем ответ в виде решения на `python` есть прямо на сайте: https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=38958

Comment: @CrazyElf, так как не сказано про лексикографический порядок, то по формальной логике надо   остановиться перед вторым A. "DDDDD" не проходит по условию "не более одной буквы A". Пример решения эту логику подтверждает.

Comment: @Сергей В решении на питоне там вообще не учтен последний `count`. Но судя по решениям буквы вообще любые могут быть, главное чтобы `A` там было не больше одного раза. Всё, теперь я вроде понял.

Comment: @Сергей почему не проходит? В "DDDDD" не более одной буквы А.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, проходит, извините. Не проснулся, видимо, когда писал:-)

Answer (score 1):

```py
    if n.count('A') > 1:
        lst.append(len(n)) # <- тут учтена лишняя буква А!
```

Вот у вас в `n` получается, что уже две буквы `A`, а вы длину **всей** этой последовательности в список добавили, включая **лишнюю** букву `A`. Последнюю `A` **не нужно учитывать**, т.е. нужно добавлять в список `len(n) - 1`.

```py
    if n.count('A') > 1:
        lst.append(len(n) - 1) # <- выкинули лишнюю А
```

Кроме того, не учтена последовательность символов в конце файла. А вдруг она длиннее всего? Поэтому уже после окончания цикла нужно добавить длину текущей последовательности (она всегда корректная, ведь `if` внутри цикла работает для этого):

```py
...
lst.append(len(n)) # <- после окончания цикла!
print(max(lst))
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли

Comment: Но ответ на задачу все еще неверный, не понимаю, почему

Comment: А есть тестовый пример, на котором ответ не верный? Или там просто пишет "ответ не верный" и всё?